# dijkstra's algorithm using matrix in c++. what's wrong in this code?

Tags: c++, algorithm, dijkstra

```
#include <iostream>



int n, m, v1, v2, weight;

cin >> n >> m;
int** graph = new int*[n];
int* distance = new int[n];
int* s = new int[n];

for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    graph[i] = new int[n];

for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
        graph[i][j] = INT_MAX;

for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i)
{
    cin >> v1 >> v2 >> weight;
    graph[v1][v2] = weight;
    graph[v2][v1] = weight;
}

for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    distance[i] = INT_MAX;


for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    distance[i] = graph[0][i];

for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    s[i] = 0;

distance[0] = 0;

int min = INT_MAX;
int vertex = 0;

for (int j = 0; j < n-1; ++j){
    min = INT_MAX;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        if (s[i] == 0 && min >= distance[i])
        {
            vertex = i;
            min = distance[i];
        }

    s[vertex] = 1;
    cout << vertex << " ";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        if (distance[i]>distance[vertex] + graph[vertex][i])
            distance[i] = distance[vertex] + graph[vertex][i];



}
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    cout << distance[i] << " ";

cout << endl;

    return 0;
```

}

Hi. I'm making Dijkstra's algorithm using two-dimentional matrix..
but this code doesn't work. and i don't know why!  Can you fix my problem??
i want to make output all distance of graph. but output is looks like array point garbage value like -2345...
Can you help me??

Comment: Off topic: Don't expect peak performance form this due to the low spacial locality  you get from arrays of arrays. Consider instead using a 1D array and doing the 2D indexing yourself with (i+j*m).

Comment: Off topic: Typically `m` and `n` are row and column lengths, but `n` is used for both row and column leaving a nasty readability issue in this code. You should consider giving `n` and `m`, and the rest of the alphabet soup variables descriptive names.

Comment: Your code doesn't even compile. Please reread the posting guidelines, in particular the thing about the minimal example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some problems in this loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        if (distance[i]>distance[vertex] + graph[vertex][i])
            distance[i] = distance[vertex] + graph[vertex][i];
```

should change to the blew code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        if (s[i] == 0 && graph[vertex][i] != INT_MAX && distance[i]>distance[vertex] + graph[vertex][i])
            distance[i] = distance[vertex] + graph[vertex][i];
```

because if the `graph[vertex][i] == INT_MAX`, the sum of `distance[vertex] + graph[vertex][i]` is overflow. Another problem is that the vertex i should not be marked before.